# Is ArrayList object copied or referenced?

Tags: java

So I'm reading [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/collision/) game tutorial and there is code to make arrayLists with aliens/missiles disappear upon collision.

```
  ArrayList ms = craft.getMissiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++) {
        Missile m = (Missile) ms.get(i);

        Rectangle r1 = m.getBounds();

        for (int j = 0; j<aliens.size(); j++) {
            Alien a = (Alien) aliens.get(j);
            Rectangle r2 = a.getBounds();

            if (r1.intersects(r2)) {
                m.setVisible(false);
                a.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the last loop, m.setVisible(false) and a.setVisible(false) make that specific alien/missile invisible but 'a' and 'm' are not part of the ArrayList they're ArrayList objects pulled out and casted into 'a' and 'm' yet the code seems to work fine given that the coder does not insert the 'a' or 'm' object back into its specific spot in the arraylist (or update its corresponding object in the arraylist).

Which makes me think, are 'a' and 'm' referenced by address to the i-th object in the arraylist as opposed to being copies?

Comment: (Relevant answers have been submitted, so...)  One thing - you shouldn't really be using that version of the `for()` loop - look up 'for-each' loops.  You don't appear to be using the index of the list, other than to get a specific element...

Comment: Thanks, I agree. But it's just that I was following a tutorial, I guess for my own implementations I'll make note of that! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. They're references. Any time you say

```
A a = new A();
```

in Java, `a` is a reference, *not* the actual object (a common source of confusion).

When you use a standard collection, getting an element from that collection will return the reference to the contained object. Consequently it's trivial to iterate through a collection and perform changes on the contained objects.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   list.get(i).clear(); // changes the object in the list...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it's trivial to "iterate through a collection and perform changes in the contained objects"? If I had an array list of strings and I wanted to add string ".com" to all of them by iterating through them, how would that be trivial? Trying to understand your statement.. thanks

Comment: @user772401 String are a special case, not as trivial, because they are immutable. So there are no mutator methods to call on the string.

Comment: @user772401 - see my amended answer

Answer (score 3):

Objects in Java are always copied by reference unless you clone them. Therefore, unless you're working with a primitive, it's being copied by reference, when you use the assignment operator or return it from a function.

Answer (score 1):

references are copied, objects are not copied unless you call something like clone().

BTW: The ArrayList contains references.  When you add a reference of an object to an ArrayList the object is not copied and it in not in the ArrayList as such.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.get()` gives you a reference to the object, not a copy.